# Signed Docker images with Google Cloud Container Registry or Artifact Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

When I try to sign a docker image in GCR or GAR I use:

`docker trust sign name:label`

But I get this error: *Error: error contacting notary server: unknown: Project 'project:XXX' not found or deleted*

Anyone have found a way in order to work with signed docker images and Google Cloud?

Comment: Are you authenticated? Are you able to perform a docker run of your image for exemple (so be able to pull it). Are you able to push an image?

Comment: I am authenticated. The problem is only when I try to sign the image.